# Ransack and display by category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I want to display users based on their type, so on the user overview page I have three headers: admins / moderators / members. Under each header I show the users that are part of that group. So I query on user_type and find all users that are belonging to this group.

Each member is also works at a certain company. I'm creating a filter that uses ransack to filter on that company:

```
= f.input :users_company_id_in, collection: Company.order(:name), label: 'Company'
```

In my controller I'm using ransack like this:

```
  def index
    @q = UserType.includes(:users, :active_users).ransack(params[:q])
    @user_types = @q.result(distinct: true)
  end
```

Since in my view I'm fetching the users by using `@user_types.users`, this query is not respecting the ransack parameters, so I'm seeing all users for every category that has someone working for that company.

What I'm trying to achieve is obviously to see only the users that work for a specific company and only display a certain user_type if there are people in the category after filtering.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: It feels a little odd that on a user overview page you are returning the `user_types`. I'd probably refactor the index action to return users instead. Then the ransack search should respect the company by changing that input to `company_id_in`. If you still want to show all 3 lists of users at the same time you'll need to add some logic to do the filtering.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue in one of my project. Here's roughly the steps you need to take:

In your controller, change the index action to this:

```
def index
  @q = User.ransack(params[:q])
  @users = @q.result(distinct: true)
end
```

This will tell Ransack to search for `users`, not `user_types`.

In your view, change the code that fetches the users to this:

```
@users = @q.result.where(company_id: params[:users_company_id_in])
```

This will filter the users by the company ID that was passed in the params.

If you want to only display a certain `user_type` if there are people in the category after filtering, you can do this with a before filter:
Ruby

```
before_filter :check_user_type

def check_user_type
  if params[:users_user_type_id].present?
    @user_type = UserType.find(params[:users_user_type_id])
    if @user_type.users.empty?
      flash[:alert] = "There are no users of this type."
      redirect_to users_path
    end
  end
end
```

This before filter will check if the user has specified a `user_type` ID in the params. If they have, it will find the `user_type` by that ID and check if there are any users of that type. If there are no users of that type, it will flash an alert message and redirect the user to the users page.